# Identify where values in a time-series have not changed

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) that looks like:

```
      Date  Price
10/11/2017    4.5
09/11/2017    4.7
08/11/2017    5.6
07/11/2017    5.6
06/11/2017    5.6
03/11/2017    5.6
02/11/2017    5.6
01/11/2017    7.9
31/10/2017    7.2
30/10/2017    7.2
31/10/2017    7.2
01/10/2017    7.2
02/10/2017    7.2
03/10/2017    7.2
```

How can I identify and return rows of the data-frame where the price from the 5th day onward has not changed following 4 consecutive days? In other words, any days greater than 4 where the price has not changed would be returned. So in the above example the following would be returned:

```
     Date  Price
02/11/2017    5.6
02/10/2017    7.2
03/10/2017    7.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rolling`:

```
df[df.Price.eq(df.Price.shift()).rolling(4).sum().eq(4)]
```

Output:

```
          Date  Price
6   02/11/2017    5.6
12  02/10/2017    7.2
13  03/10/2017    7.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this via `groupby`:

```
c = df.Price.diff() == 0 
df[c.groupby(c.ne(c.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum() >= 4]

         Date  Price
6  2017-02-11    5.6
12 2017-02-10    7.2
13 2017-03-10    7.2
```

The idea is to figure out how many consecutive rows have the same price, then filter all rows which have not changed for 4 or more days.